# iOS Objective-C: Determine current 3D rotation of a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, quartz-graphics

I am trying to determine the current 3D rotation of a UIView. I know that to get the 2D rotation is:

```
CGFloat radians = atan2f(view.transform.b, view.transform.a);
```

Not sure how to get the current 3D rotation. I want to be able to autoreverse the animation and preserve its starting point. The rotation of the object may have been affected by a previous rotation via user input so I can't assume its starting value. I store the last user-defined angle on a property of the object, I think that's fine in  practice, but I'd love to know how to get the info. I've done a lot of research on this but can't find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case, a 4x4 matrix might contain perspective, (non-uniform) scaling, (non-uniform) shearing, rotation (around a possibly-not-axis-aligned vector), and translation.  If you want to extract the rotation in the general case, you need to decompose the matrix into components for each of these “simple” transformations.

[Graphics Gems II](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0120644819) §VII.1 describes an algorithm for this. Appendix II provides code for the algorithm. The code can be found [online here](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gemsii/unmatrix.c). The header file is [here](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/gemsii/unmatrix.h). You'll also need some supporting files like the “C utilities” so [check this link too](http://tog.acm.org/resources/GraphicsGems/category.html).

The book's preface declares the code to be in the public domain, so I reproduce it below.

```
/* unmatrix.c - given a 4x4 matrix, decompose it into standard operations.
 *
 * Author:  Spencer W. Thomas
 *      University of Michigan
 */
#include <math.h>
#include "GraphicsGems.h"
#include "unmatrix.h"

/* unmatrix - Decompose a non-degenerate 4x4 transformation matrix into
 *  the sequence of transformations that produced it.
 * [Sx][Sy][Sz][Shearx/y][Sx/z][Sz/y][Rx][Ry][Rz][Tx][Ty][Tz][P(x,y,z,w)]
 *
 * The coefficient of each transformation is returned in the corresponding
 * element of the vector tran.
 *
 * Returns 1 upon success, 0 if the matrix is singular.
 */
int
unmatrix( mat, tran )
Matrix4 *mat;
double tran[16];
{
    register int i, j;
    Matrix4 locmat;
    Matrix4 pmat, invpmat, tinvpmat;
    /* Vector4 type and functions need to be added to the common set. */
    Vector4 prhs, psol;
    Point3 row[3], pdum3;

    locmat = *mat;
    /* Normalize the matrix. */
    if ( locmat.element[3][3] == 0 )
        return 0;
    for ( i=0; i<4;i++ )
        for ( j=0; j<4; j++ )
            locmat.element[i][j] /= locmat.element[3][3];
    /* pmat is used to solve for perspective, but it also provides
     * an easy way to test for singularity of the upper 3x3 component.
     */
    pmat = locmat;
    for ( i=0; i<3; i++ )
        pmat.element[i][3] = 0;
    pmat.element[3][3] = 1;

    if ( det4x4(&pmat) == 0.0 )
        return 0;

    /* First, isolate perspective.  This is the messiest. */
    if ( locmat.element[0][3] != 0 || locmat.element[1][3] != 0 ||
        locmat.element[2][3] != 0 ) {
        /* prhs is the right hand side of the equation. */
        prhs.x = locmat.element[0][3];
        prhs.y = locmat.element[1][3];
        prhs.z = locmat.element[2][3];
        prhs.w = locmat.element[3][3];

        /* Solve the equation by inverting pmat and multiplying
         * prhs by the inverse.  (This is the easiest way, not
         * necessarily the best.)
         * inverse function (and det4x4, above) from the Matrix
         * Inversion gem in the first volume.
         */
        inverse( &pmat, &invpmat );
        TransposeMatrix4( &invpmat, &tinvpmat );
        V4MulPointByMatrix(&prhs, &tinvpmat, &psol);

        /* Stuff the answer away. */
        tran[U_PERSPX] = psol.x;
        tran[U_PERSPY] = psol.y;
        tran[U_PERSPZ] = psol.z;
        tran[U_PERSPW] = psol.w;
        /* Clear the perspective partition. */
        locmat.element[0][3] = locmat.element[1][3] =
            locmat.element[2][3] = 0;
        locmat.element[3][3] = 1;
    } else      /* No perspective. */
        tran[U_PERSPX] = tran[U_PERSPY] = tran[U_PERSPZ] =
            tran[U_PERSPW] = 0;

    /* Next take care of translation (easy). */
    for ( i=0; i<3; i++ ) {
        tran[U_TRANSX + i] = locmat.element[3][i];
        locmat.element[3][i] = 0;
    }

    /* Now get scale and shear. */
    for ( i=0; i<3; i++ ) {
        row[i].x = locmat.element[i][0];
        row[i].y = locmat.element[i][1];
        row[i].z = locmat.element[i][2];
    }

    /* Compute X scale factor and normalize first row. */
    tran[U_SCALEX] = V3Length(&row[0]);
    row[0] = *V3Scale(&row[0], 1.0);

    /* Compute XY shear factor and make 2nd row orthogonal to 1st. */
    tran[U_SHEARXY] = V3Dot(&row[0], &row[1]);
    (void)V3Combine(&row[1], &row[0], &row[1], 1.0, -tran[U_SHEARXY]);

    /* Now, compute Y scale and normalize 2nd row. */
    tran[U_SCALEY] = V3Length(&row[1]);
    V3Scale(&row[1], 1.0);
    tran[U_SHEARXY] /= tran[U_SCALEY];

    /* Compute XZ and YZ shears, orthogonalize 3rd row. */
    tran[U_SHEARXZ] = V3Dot(&row[0], &row[2]);
    (void)V3Combine(&row[2], &row[0], &row[2], 1.0, -tran[U_SHEARXZ]);
    tran[U_SHEARYZ] = V3Dot(&row[1], &row[2]);
    (void)V3Combine(&row[2], &row[1], &row[2], 1.0, -tran[U_SHEARYZ]);

    /* Next, get Z scale and normalize 3rd row. */
    tran[U_SCALEZ] = V3Length(&row[2]);
    V3Scale(&row[2], 1.0);
    tran[U_SHEARXZ] /= tran[U_SCALEZ];
    tran[U_SHEARYZ] /= tran[U_SCALEZ];

    /* At this point, the matrix (in rows[]) is orthonormal.
     * Check for a coordinate system flip.  If the determinant
     * is -1, then negate the matrix and the scaling factors.
     */
    if ( V3Dot( &row[0], V3Cross( &row[1], &row[2], &pdum3) ) < 0 )
        for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
            tran[U_SCALEX+i] *= -1;
            row[i].x *= -1;
            row[i].y *= -1;
            row[i].z *= -1;
        }

    /* Now, get the rotations out, as described in the gem. */
    tran[U_ROTATEY] = asin(-row[0].z);
    if ( cos(tran[U_ROTATEY]) != 0 ) {
        tran[U_ROTATEX] = atan2(row[1].z, row[2].z);
        tran[U_ROTATEZ] = atan2(row[0].y, row[0].x);
    } else {
        tran[U_ROTATEX] = atan2(-row[2].x, row[1].y);
        tran[U_ROTATEZ] = 0;
    }
    /* All done! */
    return 1;
}


/* transpose rotation portion of matrix a, return b */
Matrix4 *TransposeMatrix4(a, b)
Matrix4 *a, *b;
{
int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
        for (j=0; j<4; j++)
            b->element[i][j] = a->element[j][i];
    return(b);
}

/* multiply a hom. point by a matrix and return the transformed point */
Vector4 *V4MulPointByMatrix(pin, m, pout)
Vector4 *pin, *pout;
Matrix4 *m;
{
    pout->x = (pin->x * m->element[0][0]) + (pin->y * m->element[1][0]) +
        (pin->z * m->element[2][0]) + (pin->w * m->element[3][0]);
    pout->y = (pin->x * m->element[0][1]) + (pin->y * m->element[1][1]) +
        (pin->z * m->element[2][1]) + (pin->w * m->element[3][1]);
    pout->z = (pin->x * m->element[0][2]) + (pin->y * m->element[1][2]) +
        (pin->z * m->element[2][2]) + (pin->w * m->element[3][2]);
    pout->w = (pin->x * m->element[0][3]) + (pin->y * m->element[1][3]) +
        (pin->z * m->element[2][3]) + (pin->w * m->element[3][3]);
        return(pout);
}
```

The Graphics Gems code produces Euler angles. Sometimes you want a different representation for a 3D rotation. In particular, a quaternion is often more convenient. You can find the WebCore implementation of this decomposition in the `decompose` function in [`TransformationMatrix.cpp`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-514/platform/graphics/transforms/TransformationMatrix.cpp). It produces a quaternion for the rotation.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: It might be cleaner and faster to save the rotation information as you apply those rotations, and then read the saved values rather than trying to extract them from the transformation matrix.

Comment: @DuncanC That's what I had done, already, but I wanted to find out how heavyweight the calculations were. 3d math is not my strong suit, I want to improve that.